# Embedding youtube videos with jwplayer

Tags: html, jwplayer

I wonder how to put Youtube videos to an html page. I've been searching for a few hours, here's what I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/swfobject.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  swfobject.registerObject("playerID", "9.0.0");
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/mediaplayer/jwplayer.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/mediaplayer/jwplayer.js'></script>

<div id='mediaplayer'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

   var flashvars = {
      'file':   'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YE7VzlLtp-4',
      'controlbar':     'bottom'
   };

   var params = {
      'allowfullscreen':        'true',
      'allowscriptaccess':      'always'
   };

   var attributes = {
      'id':                     'playerID',
      'name':                   'playerID'
   };

   swfobject.embedSWF('Scripts/mediaplayer/player.swf', 'mediaplayer', '480', '360', '9', 'false', flashvars, params, attributes);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

            <head>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='./Scripts/swfobject.js'></script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='./Scripts/mediaplayer/jwplayer.js'></script>

            <div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

            <script type='text/javascript'>
              jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
                'flashplayer': './Scripts/mediaplayer/player.swf',
                'file': 'http://www.youtube.com/v/K_sev04KfeU?version',
                'controlbar': 'bottom',
                'width': '470',
                'height': '320'
              });
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

and

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

            <head>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='./Scripts/mediaplayer/jwplayer.js'></script>

            </head>
            <body>


            <div id='mediaplayer'></div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
              jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
                'flashplayer': './Scripts/mediaplayer/player.swf',
                'id': 'playerID',
                'width': '480',
                'height': '270',
                'file': 'XSGBVzeBUbk',
                'provider': 'youtube',
                'plugins': {
                   'hd-2': {}
                }
              });
            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

and tens of variations (including registerObject)... I wonder if someone could give me an example .zip link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by moving script tag to the top. Thanks for the helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="tr">
<head>
<title>My Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<meta name="keywords" content="foreign trade, hazelnut, livestocks, sunflower, rice, wheat, lentil, sunflower oil" />
<meta name="description" content="Comparative Nutrition Values: Brown & White Grain Rice table" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="01 jan 1970 00:00:00 gmt" />
<meta http-equiv="last-modified" content="01 jan 1970 00:00:00 gmt" />
<meta http-equiv="if-modified-since" content="01 jan 1970 00:00:00 gmt" />
<link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-ico" href="../favicon.ico" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../favicon.ico" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just use their example script and modify the paths to where you uploaded the player

```
<div id="movieframe">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mysite.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<div id="mediaspace" style='width:640px;height:480px;'></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
            'flashplayer': 'http://www.mysite.com/jwplayer/player.swf',
            'file': 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YE7VzlLtp-4',
            'image': 'http://www.mysite.com/graphics/splash.jpg',
            'controlbar': 'bottom',
            'width': '640',
            'height': '480'
        });
    </script>
</div>
</div>
```

You need to call this script only once

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mysite.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.js">
```

It can be in the `<head>` tag or right before you're showing it, but you don't need both.
Normally jwplayer.js and player.swf are in the same directory. If you don't include the correct path it will not work - your examples use several different paths.

Comment: thanks for the reply. this code can't load the movie with local html http://sudrap.org/paste/text/186014/

Comment: the path needs to point to where you uploaded player.swf and jwplayer.js . I don't understand what you mean by local html

Comment: yes, the files are in jwplayer folder.I mean I didn't test the code on a server.

Comment: Probably you need to test it and come back and say if it works or not

Comment: the problem continues when i leave my dns settings default and test the page.